# Select query with calculation on rows one after another SQL

Tags: sql

Table **Movements**

```
MovementType | ItemID | qtty
============================
1            | 55     |  5 |
1            | 55     |  2 |
1            | 55     |  3 |
5            | 55     |  2 |
1            | 56     |  5 |
1            | 56     |  5 |
```

The type is 1 for sold items and 5 for returned items.
i want to print a receipt. so i want to select sold items information with duplicates but minus returned items.
Like this `

```
MovementType | ItemID | qtty
============================
1            | 55     |  3 |
1            | 55     |  2 |
1            | 55     |  3 |
```

OR

```
MovementType | ItemID | qtty
============================
1            | 55     |  4 |
1            | 55     |  1 |
1            | 55     |  3 |
```

my query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT   (ISNULL(PSM.qtty,0) - ISNULL(SM.qtty,0)) AS qtty, ItemID, --..........
FROM Movements PSM
LEFT OUTER JOIN Movements as SM on PSM.ItemID = SM.ItemID AND SM.MovementType = 5
WHERE  (PSM.ID = 1) AND (PSM.MovementType = 1) --AND ........
```

but its return like this

```
MovementType | ItemID | qtty
============================
1            | 55     |  3 |
1            | 55     |  0 |
1            | 55     |  1 |
```

i have transaction ID and more columns, this receipt for cafe. and the customer can buy anything in different times, and can return some off it. there are two receipts, first for the employees to ready the orders (TEMP receipt). so i cannot remove the duplicates because the quantity will duplicates (New and old orders) and i have sorted the orders to know what orders requested first. and for the customers (Final receipt) would be contains duplicates of requested orders, but minus the returned from any row that contains same item ordered before.
so my query will minus the returned quantity from all rows that's contain same item and that's the problem.

Comment: Which database system are you using? Is it SQL Server?

Comment: How do you get from your `Movements` table to your `LIke this` results? And why are there 2? What's different in them?

Comment: And how are you ordering them? You need a column that will provide a reliable order to be able to have a running total.

Comment: Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking. In your `Movements` table, you `sold` 10 of `ItemID=55` and returned 2. Does that mean you want to include 8 of `ItemID` 55 and 10 of `ItemID` 56 (according to your example? I don't understand the calculations you're using in your `Like this` examples.

Comment: Unless you have a way of linking a return to a specific purchase (for example, using a transaction ID), I don't see how you decide to subtract the return from just one of the entries. It could be done - possibly by subtracting from the first possible entry, but it creates a lot of unnecessary work. Why not just use a SUM? DO you need to keep all the different sales of a specific item separate? With SUM, you could use CASE WHEN to change any entry with movement_type = 5 to a negative value prior to SUM. Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d97688/4

Comment: yes i have transaction ID and more columns, this receipt for cafe. and the customer can buy anything in different times, and can return some off it. there are two receipts, first for the employees to ready the orders (TEMP receipt). so i cannot remove the duplicates because the quantity will duplicates (New and old orders) and i have sorted the orders to know what orders requested first. and for the customers (Final receipt) would be contains duplicates of requested orders, but minus the returned from any row that contains same item ordered before.

Comment: my query will minus the returned quantity from all rows that's contain same item and that's the problem.
the problem was fixed but using c#. but if anyone can tell me it's possible in SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and then aggregate:

```
select (case when sum(case when movementType = 1 then qtty
                           when movementType = 5 then - qtty
                      end) >= 0
             then 1 else 5
        end) as movementType,
       itemId,
       sum(case when movementType = 1 then qtty
                when movementType = 5 then - qtty
           end) as qtty
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemId, movementType order by itemId) as seqnum
      from movements m
     ) m
group by itemId, seqnum;
```

That said, I think the receipt would be clearer with separate rows for the returns.

Comment: I'm very thanks. but the duplicates is required! you can do it?

Comment: @SayedMahmoud . . . I'm not sure what your comment intends.  This still produces what I would call duplicates.

Comment: . . but i have more columns after i add it must be included in group by

Comment: @SayedMahmoud . . . This answers the question that you asked in this question.  The columns are quite well defined.  If you have *another* question, please ask it as a *new* question.